# why is my hyperlink css not working

Tags: html, css

I have tried and tried to fix this issue, but i don't know what is going on. Basically i have hyperlinks on my html which i want to change from blue to something else. However for some reason it just wont work, i managed to get rid of the underline but i cant change the color.

**HTML**

```
        <nav align="middle">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" class="home" style="height:80px; width:80px;"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Games</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
        </ul>



    </nav>
```

**CSS**

```
li {

display: inline;
margin-right: .75em;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 60px;

}

html,body {
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;  
}

a {
color: black;
text-decoration: inherit;
}

ul {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 2px solid #ccc;
border-width: 3px 0;  

}
```

Comment: Use `a:link, a:visited` instead of just `a`. `a` by itself is not specific enough to override the standard rules setting the color blue. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318612/css-link-color-not-working for an example

Comment: Check with something like dev tools in chrome or firefox. I bet you have another style overwriting it.

Comment: i tried but i doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

```
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: #FF0000;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: #00FF00;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: #FF00FF;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: #0000FF;
}
```

Fore more information click [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp).

Comment: @usernameisnotprogrammedyet works for me see http://jsfiddle.net/3np001fq/ try using inline css (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp) does that work?